# Why is the patch version not auto incrementing when using GitVersion?

Tags: azure-pipelines, gitversion

I'm using Azure pipelines to set a version number using GitVersion.
Here is the pipeline:

```
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      displayName: 'Setup GitVersion'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '5.x'
    
    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      displayName: 'Run GitVersion'
      inputs:
        useConfigFile: true
        configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'
```

It seems to run without any problems but the patch number is never incremented. It doesn't work when I add `+semver: patch` to the commit message either.

It seems the **FullSemVer** is affected: `0.8.0+11`
But I'm expecting: `0.8.11`

Here is the **GitVersion.yml** file

```
next-version: 0.7.0
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-informational-format: '{InformationalVersion}'
mode: ContinuousDelivery
increment: Patch
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
commit-date-format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT. Apologies for the slow reply. I haven't had a chance to test it yet as a step in the same pipeline previous to this one has stopped working! (different problem) I'll update the answer as soon as I've had a go.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your update. Feel free to let me know if it could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems the FullSemVer is affected: 0.8.0+11

When I use the `ContinuousDelivery mode`, I could get the same result.

You could try to use the `mainline mode` in yml file.

Here is my example: You could try to remove the `next-version` parameter

```
mode: mainline
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
assembly-informational-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}'
```

Here is a doc about [Gitversion Mainline mode](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/modes/mainline).

**Result:**

[image]

The patch will auto incremente

Comment: Cheers, looks like it was the `mainline` bit I had wrong